# wp_mail unsubscription link

Tags: php, wordpress, newsletter

I'm sending Newsletter templates to my subscribers using wp_mail function. I am simply retrieving my subscribers list from my db and passing it in wp_mail function as an array as $to. Now the problem is, I want to add unsubscribe link to my emailer. All I want to achieve is a way to add reciever's email address in my unsubscription's hyperlink as a parameter so that i can use it for unsubscription. i.e www.mysiteurl.com/?user_email=useremail@domain.in

```
//php code
ob_start();
    //including newsletter template
    include '/newsletter-template.php';
    $message = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    //adding filter to allow <html> tags in message body
    add_filter( 'wp_mail_content_type', 'newsletter_content_type' );
    @wp_mail( $subscriberListArray, 'Testing Newsletter', $message, 'From: myWebsite <newsletter@myWebsite.com>' );
    //removing <html> tags filter once mail is sent
    remove_filter( 'wp_mail_content_type', 'newsletter_content_type' );

//html part
<div>
  <a href="www.mysiteurl.com/?user_email={dynamic_value}">unsubscribe</a>
</div>
```

above codes are working fine but i want to insert email of the current subscriber in my template file. is there any way to doing this?
thank you.

Comment: What you mean to say to add user to my template file ?

Comment: @SudharshanNair i want to get the email of my subscriber in my template file. for example if I'm sending the newsletter, so my unsubscribe link should be like www.myWebsite.com/unsubscribe?email=sudharshan@nair.com. I can't send mail within loop.

Comment: Can you go through this link ? Here just try to append your link in body at last
https://generatewp.com/allow-multiple-recipients-wordpress-mail/